# Tags "Types" and their Usage

Tags: discussion, tags, site-policy

This is a question spawned from @Mat's Mug's [comment](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7022/why-are-tags-functional-programming-and-haskell-mutually-exclusive/7023?noredirect=1#comment16049_7023) on a question I had about a tag removal.

It seems that there is some consensus among the more senior users here about the way some tags should be used. Best thing to do is read @Mat's Mug's [answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7023/76711) to my question for what I mean, but I'll explain here the best I can.

---

Tags such as [functional-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) and [oop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oop) indicate programming paradigms. They're indicators for the discourse of discussion that should take place: is the OP grappling with the concept of functional programming, and looking for a review of what is messy and inefficient beginner code? This deserves a [functional-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) tag.

Is it a question about Haskell which by necessity involves [functional-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming)? Well then the question is not so much about the paradigm of functional programming itself; it's just an incidental matter. As such, a [functional-programming](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) tag on a [haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haskell) question may even be removed as in [this case](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142388/large-power-mod-extreme-efficiency).

Unfortunately, as a junior member of this community, I am not blessed with the arcane knowledge required to appropriately use tags which seem to me to be perfectly appropriate.

### And So...

...can the codereview.SE community herein establish a protocol of appropriate tagging?

Comment: I'm (not so) secretly hoping that someone edits this question just to change the tags.

Comment: wish granted :)

Comment: @Vogel612 - I'm so happy that the edit was legitimate, too.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5071/tagging-categories-which-are-most-useful

Comment: @Vogel612 somehow I hadn't seen that one before, good find!

Comment: @Vogel612 - Good find indeed. I think that contains a lot of the answer, but there is a little more to be said on how these categories should be applied.